# Why is the mark ring called a 'ring' and not a 'stack'?

Tags: mark, mark-ring

From the description of the mark ring on the Emacs website ([link](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Mark.html)) it seems to me that it is basically just a stack with a maximum size set to be 16. So I am curious why this data-structure is called a "ring" in Emacs parlance and not a mark "stack" which intuitively seems a more reasonable name.

As a side question, what is the mark ring internally implemented as?

Comment: It's a list.  See the documentation that you linked.

Comment: Just for info: What you call "*the Emacs website (link)*" is a web-page version of the Emacs manual, which you have access to within Emacs using `C-h r`.

Comment: Sorry; I meant that it is a web-page version of the Elisp manual, which you have access to within Emacs using `C-h i` and choosing `Elisp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Elisp manual, node [Rings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rings.html), tells you about **rings** in Emacs.

It starts off with a description:

> A **ring** is a fixed-size data structure that supports insertion, deletion, rotation, and modulo-indexed reference and traversal. An efficient ring data structure is implemented by the `ring` package. It provides the functions listed in this section.
>
> Note that several rings in Emacs, like the *kill ring* and the *mark ring*, are actually implemented as simple lists, not using the ring package...

As you can see from the basic ring functions described there, a ring is not just a list or just a stack.  It has its own set of properties.

But the `mark-ring` is a list (of former marks). It is used together with the (current) `mark`.  You can use it like a stack, but you can also directly access any of its elements.